# undefined reference by the shared lib during linking to application

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling

For one of my  c++ based application I making some of my code as shared lib(c++ devlopment only) and I link to my test application to access the services of the shared lib . everything work fine when I am doing on linux .. Since I have developed this for arm based embedded system . I tried to cross compile my shared lib and application using arm cross tool chain set-up  on linux platform. I have written a makefile to create a shared lib and compile my application .
when I do the cross compile my library gets created but while linking to the application it gives the following error .

lib/arm//libserviceclient.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_string, std::allocator >::_S_compare(unsigned int, unsigned int)'

libserviceclient.so.0.2.0 is my shared lib and below are the links
libserviceclient.so.0 -> libserviceclient.so.0.2.0
libserviceclient.so -> libserviceclient.so.0

so I thought this is the problem with libstdc++ and I used that link in the make file

if I link static lib in my makefile -L/usr/local/cross/arm/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/armv4t/usr/lib/libstdc++.a it compiles but if I link shared arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/armv4t/usr/lib/libstdc++.so then it throws same error .

wouldnt be this libstdc++ linked by default if I use c++ ?
Can someone help to fix this issue .

Comment: What is your actual full resulting link command?

Comment: These are the libs I am including LIBS = -pthread -lcurl -lssl /usr/local/cross/arm/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/armv4t/usr/lib/libstdc++.so  CXX =/PATHtoarmg++                                                        $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $+ $(CFLAGS) $(INC_DIR) $(LIBS)

Comment: Try adding the library *path*.  It is `-L/usr/local/cross/arm/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/armv4t/usr/lib`.  There maybe other shared libraries there.  You only specify the *libstdc++.so*.  These libraries have to match the target (or at least be compatible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this problem ,, there was mis macth in the version of stdc++ which I was using on the development system and target system .. I used that same version on both , now it works .. thanks guys for your help